# Emberjs rendering wrong template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am working with EmberJs and can't figure out why the following code won't render the 'new' template. When I navigate to /shops, I get a list of shops and a create button linking to '/shops/new', but when I click create, the 'new' template isn't rendered and instead stays the same as 'shops'.  I can navigate to each individual shop fine, just not new.

App.js

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});

// Router
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('shops', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('shop', { path: '/shops/:shop_id' });
});

App.ShopsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Shop.find();
  }
});

App.ShopsNewRoute = App.ShopsRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Shop.createRecord();
  },
  setupController: function( controller, model ) {
    return this._super(),
    controller.set( 'content', model )
  }
});

App.ShopsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

// Models
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
});

App.Shop = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ember/Rails App</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h1>Ordr</h1>
          <hr>
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </script> 

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shops/new">
      <h2>New Shop</h2>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shops">
      {{#each shop in controller}}
        {{#linkTo "shop" shop}} {{ shop.id }}{{/linkTo}}
      {{/each}}

      {{#linkTo 'shops.new'}}Create{{/linkTo}}
    </script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shop">
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <p>{{body}}</p>
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have set up your routes and templates, you are telling Ember that you want to navigate to `shops.new` and keep all the list of shops showing even while you are in `shops.new`.

If that is in fact the scenario that you want, all you need to do is add an `{{outlet}}` inside the `shops` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shops">
  {{#each shop in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "shop" shop}} {{ shop.id }}{{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}

  {{#linkTo 'shops.new'}}Create{{/linkTo}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

However, if that is not what you really intend, and you actually want the list of shops to be hidden when you transition to `shops.new`, then you will need to change a couple of things.

change your `App.ShopsRoute` to `App.ShopsIndexRoute` :

```
App.ShopsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('shop');
  }
});
```

and your `shops` template to `shops/index` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shops/index">
  {{#each shop in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "shop" shop}} {{ shop.id }}{{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}

  {{#linkTo 'shops.new'}}Create{{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

Any of those 2 methods should fix your problem, depending on what your intentions are.

Comment: wonderful.  The second answer is what I was looking for, thank you